# Remove yellow bracket highlighting in netbeans 8.2

Tags: netbeans, syntax-highlighting, highlight, code-editor

Please can someone help me figure out how to remove the dam yellow highlighting from the brackets in NetBeans and how to change the cursor color. I've tried changing the cursor color but it stays white when I edit it!

I went to **Tools --> Options --> Highlighting --> Caret Color** and it has no effect at all.

[image: Here you can see the yellow highlighting im to disable]

Comment: Are you using third party theme?

Comment: I downloaded a Molokai theme from the netbeans website. Is that 3rd party?

Comment: Yes, it's third party. But, I don't think that error is due to this plugin. It's a IDE feature. Even I too get this yellow color highlighting for brackets with default theme. Not sure whether we can disable it or not.

Comment: That sucks because my cursor is white and when the brackets get highlighted i cant see the cursor and then when i tried to set the cursor to black it just stayed white :/